# Enforcing range in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, range

Quick, probably super basic question. If I declare an array of 10 doubles and prompt a user to input how many double they want in the index (between 1 and 10, obviously), how would I enforce that range? I assume with an if/else statement, but is there a more optimal way to enforce that range?

Again, probably really simple. I'm new so not yet familiar C++ or JavaScript.

Comment: 1) prompt for number of items to input 2) run a loop for that many items, or 10, whichever is less. 3) ??? 4) profit

Comment: Why don't you try something and write to us if you get stuck?

Comment: Why you are not trying variable length arrays?

Comment: It looks like you're in the same class as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433457/input-size-of-a-queue-by-the-user

Comment: You can't force the user to type something, but you can look at what they typed and ask them to type something else if it was unacceptable

Answer (score 1):

Get that no. of elements from user till that no. is not within your range.

Say n is number that you want in range 1 to 10.

**Solution:**

```
int n = 0;
while(n<1 || n>10)    {
    printf("Enter Correct value on n i.e. within range 1 to 10:\t");
    scanf("%d", &n);
}
```

Comment: You should initialize the integer n

Comment: You should also check the return from `scanf()`; if the user types `a`, the loop is going to run for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution maybe if you wrap the value within the required range using % (modulo) operator.

```
int n;
int arr[10];
printf("Enter a number : ");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("%d",arr[n%10]);
```

The expression `n%10` will always result in a value between 0 to 9.

**Edit (for a better validation):**

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int x, n;
    int arr[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    printf("Enter a number : ");
    if( scanf("%d",&n)!=1 )
    {
        printf("Not a valid integer!!");
        return;
    }
    n=(n<0)?-n:n;
    printf("%d",arr[n%10]);
}
```

Comment: The modulus operator is not guaranteed to return a positive value between 0 and 9 when the user types -5… And the number is supposed to be between 1 and 10, rather than 0 and 9.  You should also check that the `scanf()` worked; if the user enters `a` or indicates EOF, there will be problems. The fixes are simple, but you have to think about all cases.

Answer (score 0):

First you should read the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/) because this is a very basic example.

Second avoid requesting code here. You should always try to found solution then post your code and your error here to correct it.

You can try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n = 0;
    while(!(n > 1 && n < 10)){
        printf("Enter an integer between 1 and 10: \n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check the return from `scanf()`; if the user types `a` (for example), the loop is going to run for a long time. Normally, when you say 'between 1 and 10', you include the end points.  Your condition excludes the end points.  Using `while (n < 1 || n > 10)` seems reasonable to me. Using negation in conditional expressions makes them harder to understand, in general.